# Java simple calculator, understanding switch and method compatibility

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, switch-statement

I have an assignment in my summer class to make a simple calculator and I'm having trouble with a couple things.

There is a menu in the beginning that asks what the user would like to do and one of the options is quit and one of the options is to square the user input.

The problem I'm having is I couldn't figure out a way to exit the program with the switch so I took it out of the switch and made a conditional and thats working.  So, I guess that's not a big deal unless someone would like to show me how I would've included it in the switch.  The problem I'm having now is squaring the user input.  The problem is the program asks the user for what they'd like to do then asks them to input two operands.  However, I only want it to ask for the one operand.  So, I put it in the conditional and it only asks for the one operand but it no longer seems to be working with the method for square and computing the results.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Menu m = new Menu();
    m.getMenu();

  }    
}       



class Menu {    
    public void getMenu() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to 00 Calculator menu, this calculator has the following options:");
        System.out.println("1 - Add " + "\n" + "2 - Subtract" + "\n"
                + "3 - Multiply" + "\n" + "4 - Divide" + "\n" 
                + "5 - Square" + "\n" + "6 - Modulus" + "\n" + "0 - Quit" );
        int optionInt = scan.nextInt();

         if (optionInt == 0) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!"); 
            return;

        }else if (optionInt == 5) {
            System.out.println("Enter the first number :");
            double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
        }else {
            System.out.println("Enter the first number :");
            double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the second number :");
            double num2 = scan.nextDouble();

            double result;
            Action option = new Action();


            switch (optionInt) {
            case 1:
                result = option.addValues(num1, num2);
                option.displayResult(result);
                break;
            case 2:
                result = option.subtractValues(num1, num2);
                option.displayResult(result);
                break;
            case 3:
                result = option.multiplyValues(num1, num2);
                option.displayResult(result);
                break;  
            case 4:
                result = option.divideValues(num1, num2);
                option.displayResult(result);
                break;  
            case 5:
                result = option.squareValues(num1, num2);
                option.displayResult(result);
                break;  
            case 6:
                result = option.modulusValues(num1, num2);
                option.displayResult(result);
                break;          
            default:
                System.out.println("You entered an incorrect option.  Goodbye.");
           } 
        }   
    }
}


class Action {

public double divideValues(double d1, double d2) {
    double result = d1 / d2;
    return result;
}

public double multiplyValues(double d1, double d2) {
    double result = d1 + d2;
    return result;
}

public double subtractValues(double d1, double d2) {
    double result = d1 - d2;
    return result;
}

public double addValues(double d1, double d2) {
    double result = d1 + d2;
    return result;
}

public double squareValues(double d1, double d2) {
    double result = Math.pow(d1, 2);
    return result;
}

public double modulusValues(double d1, double d2) {
    double result = d1 % d2;
    return result;
}

public void displayResult(double result) {
    System.out.println("The answer is " + result);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the complexity of your requirements, the exit option is best left where it is...

Now, if you don't select `0`, there are two possibilities, either you need to ask for one or two values based on the options needs.

In this case, if `optionInt != 5`, then you need two values, BUT, you ALWAYS need one, so you can always ask for, for example...

```
if (optionInt == 0) {
    System.out.println("Goodbye!"); 
    return;
} else {
    System.out.println("Enter the first number :");
    double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
    double num2 = 0;
    if (optionInt != 5) {
        System.out.println("Enter the second number :");
        num2 = scan.nextDouble();
    }
    double result;
    Action option = new Action();


    switch (optionInt) {
    case 1:
        result = option.addValues(num1, num2);
        option.displayResult(result);
        break;
    case 2:
        result = option.subtractValues(num1, num2);
        option.displayResult(result);
        break;
    case 3:
        result = option.multiplyValues(num1, num2);
        option.displayResult(result);
        break;  
    case 4:
        result = option.divideValues(num1, num2);
        option.displayResult(result);
        break;  
    case 5:
        result = option.squareValues(num1); // You will need to update your Action class
        option.displayResult(result);
        break;  
    case 6:
        result = option.modulusValues(num1, num2);
        option.displayResult(result);
        break;          
    default:
        System.out.println("You entered an incorrect option.  Goodbye.");
   } 

}
```

Having read through the code, it doesn't seem that you even need to check for the exit option, as your method will exit once you've completed the actions any way, so instead, you could simply do something like...

```
if (optionInt != 0) {  
    // Process other options...
}

//... method will exit of it's own accord, you don't need to do anything...
```

**Updated**

Another approach might be to write a method to prompt the user for the values you need, when you need them, for example...

```
public double getDouble(String prompt) {
    System.out.println(prompt);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double value = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine();
    return value;
}

public void getMenu() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to 00 Calculator menu, this calculator has the following options:");
    System.out.println("1 - Add " + "\n" + "2 - Subtract" + "\n"
            + "3 - Multiply" + "\n" + "4 - Divide" + "\n"
            + "5 - Square" + "\n" + "6 - Modulus" + "\n" + "0 - Quit");
    int optionInt = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    double result;
    Action option = new Action();
    switch (optionInt) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Good bye!");
            break;
        case 1:
            result = option.addValues(
                    getDouble("Enter the first number :"),
                    getDouble("Enter the second number :")
            );
            option.displayResult(result);
            break;
        case 2:
            result = option.subtractValues(
                    getDouble("Enter the first number :"),
                    getDouble("Enter the second number :")
            );
            option.displayResult(result);
            break;
        case 3:
            result = option.multiplyValues(
                    getDouble("Enter the first number :"),
                    getDouble("Enter the second number :")
            );
            option.displayResult(result);
            break;
        case 4:
            result = option.divideValues(
                    getDouble("Enter the first number :"),
                    getDouble("Enter the second number :")
            );
            option.displayResult(result);
            break;
        case 5:
            result = option.squareValues(
                    getDouble("Enter a number :"),
            );
            option.displayResult(result);
            break;
        case 6:
            result = option.modulusValues(
                    getDouble("Enter the first number :"),
                    getDouble("Enter the second number :")
            );
            option.displayResult(result);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You entered an incorrect option.  Goodbye.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be more preferable you think?  The updated version seems more clean to me.

Comment: @user3862586 The updated version is cleaner, but also a little more complicated, as you need to call the `getDouble` method for each case, but to my mind, it's a little easier to read.  It will come down to your own needs as to which one is more suited to your needs, me personally, I be using the last version ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works great and I like the updated way better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (optionInt) {
        case 0: // simply add a case for 'quit'
            return;
        case 1:
            result = option.addValues(num1, num2);
            option.displayResult(result);
            break;
```

Comment: I had a case 0: for quit but, it would still ask for the user inputs before it would quit.  So, I tried turning each time the user entered an operand into a method and it got super confusing so I put it back and added a conditional.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, the user is asked to choose an option, when she chooses "0" the program will quit. What was confusing about it ? please post the code that implemented this approach that didn't work and we'll help you figure out what was wrong.

Comment: It was the same exact code as above except the conditionals were removed.  So what would happen is it would ask the user to enter in an option from the menu, they'd enter 0 and it would then ask them to enter the first number then enter the second number then it would head to the switch where it would exit.

Comment: The code above does not have this kind of behavior you described. If the user enters "0" it will exit (return).

Comment: Not if you take out the conditionals.  Since I got my answer I'll edit my original post to show you what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to put the option to quit back in your switch, instead of using "return" you can use System.exit(0);

That should let you quit out of the calculator and let's the caller know everything went OK.  If there's a problem, then you should use System.exit(1);  <--- there isn't a problem though if the user selected to quit.

Comment: I'm an old stick in the mud and even the OP's current approach makes me a little uneasy, but I was always taught that an method should only have one entry and one exit point and the same should hold true for a program, a program shouldn't exit in the middle somewhere...IMHO

Answer (score 0):

**To make your code Work** I don't know in your method `squareValues(double d1,double d2)`, why there are `two arguments` if you are `utilizing only one`. But to get your code working replace the following code snippet with

```
else if (optionInt == 5) {
            System.out.println("Enter the first number :");
            double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
```

this one

```
else if (optionInt == 5) {
            System.out.println("Enter the first number :");
            double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
Action option = new Action();
 result = option.squareValues(num1, num2);//num2 is useless here,remove it from your squareValues method too
            option.displayResult(result);
```

}

and remove the `case 5:` from `switch` statement